# How can I print to a hp officejet j5780 printer without the color cartridge?

Tags: printer

My color cartridge is out and I want to print a gray scale picture.  However, the printer flashes replace cartridge (when the cartridge is in), and insert cartridge when I take it out.  I don't have a spare color cartridge and the black and white is fine.  I'm printing in gray scale but can't get the printer to get past the error message?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/45013/printer-doesnt-print-pictures) was answered by pointing out that a color cartridge is *sometimes* necessary for greyscale printing.

A different printer was discussed, but the reasoning may be the same.

Comment: I was able to print from Windows 7 by going into the Color tab and specifying not only gray scale, but that the gray scale only use the B/W cartridge.